# Astrophysical "unitised" version of the Gravitational constant

Tags: units

This question relates formalising the gravitational constant, $G$, (which in S.I. units is usually quoted as $\sim6.67\times10^{-11}\,\mathrm{m}^{3}\,\mathrm{kg}^{-1}\,\mathrm{s}^{-2}$) in units which are more appropriate to astrophysics, such as in the field of galaxy dynamics.

What would $G$ be in more appropriate units to astrophysics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Useful formulations which have taken some time to dig out:

$G\sim{4.3\times{10^{-6}}}\,\mathrm{kpc}\,\mathrm{M}_{\odot}^{-1}\,\mathrm{km}^{2}\,\mathrm{s}^{-2}$

or

$G\sim{4.3\times{10^{-3}}}\,\mathrm{pc}\,\mathrm{M}_{\odot}^{-1}\,\mathrm{km}^{2}\,\mathrm{s}^{-2}$

Comment: Typo corrected, should have read pc not kpc. Thank you for the spot.